# Laravel dependency injection doesn't work while register class in AppServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

think about this scenario:
I have a class (for example A) with this constructor. :

```
    public function __construct(SocialChannelContract $channel, CallBackQueryDVO $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->channel = $channel;
    }
```

and this is the register method in AppServiceProvider:

```
   $this->app->singleton(SocialChannelContract::class, MyChannel::class);
```

now I want to create an instance of class A.

```
   return new A($callBackQueryDVO);
```

But it returns me this error that you should pass parameter 1 to class A while I introduce the class in AppServiceProvider. what is wrong in this example?

Comment: Dependency injection in Laravel happens via the application [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container) so you'll need to do e.g. `app()->make(A::class)` in order to have it construct your class and inject its dependencies

Comment: I find the solution. we should not use new command for create class. we should use app() to create class in application.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use constructor injection you need to let the service container make the class:

- `App::make(A::class);`
- `app(A::class);`
- `app()->make(A::class);`

If you want to create the class manually you need to give the constructor all the arguments.

`$channel = new SocialChannelContract(...);` or `$channel = app(SocialChannelContract::class);`

Then, `new A($channel, $myOtherStuff, ...)`
Then